# Tensorflow error on Ubuntu 20.10: ImportError: cannot import name 'run' from 'absl.app'

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, tensorflow2.0

Everytime I try to import tensorflow in python 3.8, it gives me:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'run' from 'absl.app'
```

I've already tried uninstalling tensorflow and protobuf and then reinstalling, no luck.

I tried with the latest version of tensorflow and tensorflow 2.3.1 (which worked on my other computer, although it has windows).

Please send help.

OS: Ubuntu 20.10
CPU: Ryzen 3 3100
Help: very much needed

Answer (score 0):

Usually `absl-py` package gets installed automatically when you install `TensorFlow` using pip.

```
pip install tensorflow==2.3
```

However, you can try installing manually `absl-py` as below:

```
pip install absl-py
```

and then

```
from absl.app import run
```